# Efficient way to compute cosine similarity between matrix and vector of different lengths?

Tags: python, matrix, vector, cosine-similarity

I am trying to compute cosine similarity between a matrix of vectors and a vector.

I am using this function:

```
    matrix_example =  [list([u'phase', u'nepal', u'formulation', u'workshop', u'janakpur', u'kamala', u'river', u'system', u'stakeholder', u'dhanusa']) list([u'ready', u'flood', u'myself', u'with', u'upcoming', u'interview', u'crack', u'video', u'escape', u'reality', u'life', u'bts_twt']) list([u'what', u'possibly', u'could', u'wrong', u'some', u'flood', u'some', u'storm', u'fire', u'trump', u'environment', u'chief', u'suggests', u'global'])]

    vector_example = [u'evidently' u'that' u'blue' u'wave' u'calmed' u'blue' u'trickle' u'every' u'looking' u'more' u'more' u'like' u'tsunami']



def cos_matrix_multiplication(matrix, vector):

    #Calculating pairwise cosine distance using matrix vector multiplication.

    dotted = np.reshape(matrix.dot(vector))
    matrix_norms = np.linalg.norm(matrix, axis=1)
    vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(vector)
    matrix_vector_norms = np.multiply(matrix_norms, vector_norm)
    neighbors = np.divide(dotted, matrix_vector_norms)
    return neighbors
```

However, I have this error which occurs because vectors in the matrix haven't the same length that my inpu vector.

```
ValueError: shapes (13,) and (11,) not aligned: 13 (dim 0) != 11 (dim 0)
```

I found some responces in order to manage with vectors of different lengths but I am not able to apply that on a matrix of vectors. I deal with a huge amount of data and it would be to long to deal by vector pairs.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to mathematically compare two vectors with different dimensions? Do you mean to zero-pad the smaller vector?

Comment: Yes maybe, or maybe It would be more efficient to use something like that all_items = set(counter1.keys()).union( set(counter2.keys()) )

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself yet? If so, and you have issues implementing it in code, we can help with that. As it stands, you don't seem to have a specific issue that we can help with yet.

Comment: In fact, I have some difficulties to see when I can introduce this. You think I need to construct a new matrix each time I have a new input vector?